# Why should a pimpl be declared as a struct and not a class?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

The canonical form of the pimpl idiom (from Herb Sutter's "Exceptional C++") is as follows:

```
class X 
{
public:
 /* ... public members ... */
protected:
 /* ... protected members? ... */ 
private:
 /* ... private members? ... */
 struct XImpl;
 XImpl* pimpl_; // opaque pointer to
                // forward-declared class 
};
```

My question is, why is `XImpl` declared as a struct instead of a class?

Comment: There is little sense is hiding something that is already hidden. The default access of `private` for a `class` vs. `public` for a `struct` seems trivially overkill.

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference whatsoever (unless your compiler is very very buggy).

Comment: @WhozCraig But that is a forward declaration. In this particular case, it makes absolutely no difference. It doesn't even save typing :-)

Comment: @juanchopanza I completely agree. its the language-difference of the word as a normal decl I was commenting on. you're absolutely right that it truly makes no functional difference at all.

Answer (score 7):

The *only* difference between `struct` and `class` is the default access control of the bases and members (public and private, respectively). You can even declare the same type with one and define it with the other (but note that some compilers can issue warnings on this).

Just use whatever is most natural to you. @WhozCraig correctly points out that since `XImpl` is already inaccessible outside of the implementation `X`, making its members `private` by default seems superfluous. Still, as I've said above, it makes no difference here at all, since it's only the keyword used for the *definition* which matters.

Comment: But it is a forward declaration, so the difference doesn't matter here (except some might get confused seeing `class` in a declaration and `struct` in the definition.)

Comment: @StilesCrisis Really? Since when? ? C++11 §11(3) [class.access] : "Members of a class defined with the keyword `class` are private by default"

Comment: Class definitely defaults to private!

Comment: @juanchopanza and some compilers even emit warnings if you define a `class` after forward-declaring it as a `struct`

Comment: @juanchopanza Right, edited the answer to that effect.

Comment: @Angew an example for the slight difference (the compiler warning mentioned above): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45b934a46a183d27 This is clang specific, it does not appear under gcc.

Comment: @ArneMertz IIRR, VS issues this warning as well. But I must say it's one of the few warnings I consider detrimental, and disable it in my projects.

Answer (score 2):

Well... I don't know why Herb Sutter has decided to use `struct`, but you can use `class` instead if you prefer, it is equivalent in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really make a difference since structs and classes are basically the same, but you probably want everything in `XImpl` to be public because it's only visible to the code that implements `X` anyway.  Using `struct` instead of `class` just saves you from having to write `public:` at the beginning of its definition.